# How to attach `\x` at the beginning of some value and make string out of it?

Tags: sass

I have written below code in sass / scss. Here i am facing an issue i.e. when i'm trying to loop and concatenate value with \ . I'm getting space when my value contains alpha numeric. Kindly suggest how to overcome form this

SCSS =>>
Input :

```
$data: (
a:2766,
b:27B3,
d:1F48C
);

@each $value1, $value2 in $data {
 .#{$value1}{
   content: str-slice("\x",1,1)+($value2);
 }
}
```

Output :

```
.a {
  content: "\2766";
}

.b {
  content: "\27B 3";
}

.d {
  content: "\1F 48C";
}
```

Comment: What Sass version do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in Sass itself. Update your Sass and your problem should be fixed.

You can see this is the case on [sass playground](https://www.sassmeister.com/). Copy and paste your sass code there and then select `Sass v3.3.14` and `Sass v3.4.21` (or any later/newer) and you'll see the difference. :)

Edit:
In order to add `\x` at the beginning, you can do it this way:

SCSS (Sass v3.4.21):

```
$data: (
  a: 2766,
  b: 27B3,
  d: 1F48C
);

@each $value1, $value2 in $data {
 .#{$value1}{
   content: str-insert(#{$value2}, "\\x", 1);
 }
}
```

CSS output:

```
.a {
  content: \x2766;
}

.b {
  content: \x27B3;
}

.d {
  content: \x1F48C;
}
```

[str-insert](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#str_insert-instance_method) puts a string inside other string.  `\\` in `\\x` escapes to single `\x`. Oh, and as the reference states, first character in sass is `1`, not `0`.

Comment: Right but if i change Sass version then in result not coming backslash, I need backslash also.


.a {
  content: "x2766";
}

.b {
  content: "x27B3";
}

.d {
  content: "x1F48C";
}

Comment: Yes, I missed the point, sorry. I edited my answer to show how to add `\x` at the beginning. You still need to update your Sass, though. :P

Comment: Ohh It's Working fine .

Thanks,
BalRam